# CSS not loading in my Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

Everything was working fine on my app, after I overhauled the entire front-end design. I attempted to push to my staging server on heroku, and I was getting issues when it was precompiling my assets. So, I attempted `rake assets:clobber && rake assets:precompile`, and now none of the css is loading in development at all. Syntax errors in my `application.sass` to bring up error pages, but it's not loading any of the css in my app. In chrome dev tools the only css files showing are SweetAlert css files.

Comment: Did you add the 12_factor gem for heroku?  Also, run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" so it uses your production env. config when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I thought you had to precompile your assets in development, but after some research I found you do not. I clobbered my assets with `rake assets:clobber` and my css began loading just fine again. Also when pushing to heroku I did nothing else, since heroku precompiles your assets on deployment